# Image inside div inside link not clickable in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have the following code in ASP.NET.

The problem is that this HyperLink(hpRecord) works for all surface of "posts_listDiv" other than the two images which are not clickable in IE 9.

I tested that code and works fine in all browsers other than Internet Explorer.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterCategories" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>                 
         <asp:HyperLink ID="hpRecord" runat="server" NavigateUrl='link'>               
           <div id="posts_listDiv" class="posts_listDiv">                                                         

             <div id="pict1Div" class="pict1Div">
                 <asp:Image ID="picture" runat="server" Width="100px"  Height="80px" ImageUrl='link'/>
             </div>                                                                                      

              <div id="pict2Div" class="pict2Div">
                 <asp:Image ID="pict2" runat="server"  Width="100px"  Height="80px" ImageUrl='link'/>                                            
               </div> 

               <div id="detailsDiv" class="detailsDiv">  
                   <%--text--%>                     
                   <%# Eval("...")%>                    
                   <br />                                                                                                                
                   <%--by user--%>                   
                   <i style="color:blue"><%# Eval("FirstName") %> </i>
                </div>
             </div>                
          </asp:HyperLink>                
       </ItemTemplate>   
     </asp:Repeater>
```

and this is CSS for "posts_listDiv":

```
.posts_listDiv
{
     background-color:red;
     margin-left:5px;
     float:left;
     width:232px;
     height:171px;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     font-size:14px;
     margin-left:8px;
     margin-top:10px;         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a style to "posts_listDiv" parent div.

```
.parent {
    display: block;
}
```